# Change dict values from tuple to set python

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I would like change my dict values to dict, not tuple like they are now. I have function which returns `i` elements of the combination n on k-places.

```
from itertools import combinations

def comb(n,k,i):
    if i <= 0 or i > n:
        return None
    d = dict((enumerate(combinations(range(1,n+1),k))))
    return d[i-1]

print(comb(5,3,1))
```

OUTPUT = `(1, 2, 3)`

EXPECTED = `{1,2,3}`

Comment: your expected output is not a valid python dict.

Comment: A dict is composed of keys and values your expected output is nonsense

Comment: You mean you want a **set**?

Answer (score 4):

Your expected output is a *set*, not a dictionary; just use `set()` on the result:

```
return set(d[i-1])
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> def comb(n,k,i):
...     if i <= 0 or i > n:
...         return None
...     d = dict((enumerate(combinations(range(1,n+1),k))))
...     return set(d[i-1])
... 
>>> print(comb(5,3,1))
{1, 2, 3}
```

To get a specific iteration of a iterable object, you could use an [`itertools.islice()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), rather than produce a dictionary with all results:

```
from itertools import combinations, islice

def comb(n, k, i):
    if not (0 > i >= n):
        return None
    d = combinations(range(1, n + 1), k)
    ith_item = next(islice(d, i - 1, None))
    return set(ith_item)
```

but there are probably more efficient ways of calculating a specific combination of n out of k than brute-forcing.